# How do I execute javascript before image load, but after content load?

Tags: javascript, image, lazy-loading

The goal is to add loading="lazy" code to every image before It's actually loaded.

I cannot add that manually.

This is what I have so far (it adds the loading attribute, but image is still loaded even above the viewport):

```
function preloadFunc()
{
  var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); 
  console.log(images.length)
  
  for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      console.log(images[i].src);

      var bounding = images[i].getBoundingClientRect();
      var myElementHeight = images[i].offsetHeight;
      var myElementWidth = images[i].offsetWidth;
  
      if (bounding.top >= -myElementHeight 
          && bounding.left >= -myElementWidth
          && bounding.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) + myElementWidth
          && bounding.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) + myElementHeight) {
  
          console.log('Element is in the viewport!');
      } else {
        images[i].setAttribute('loading', 'lazy');
  
          console.log('Element is NOT in the viewport!');
      }
  } 
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", preloadFunc);
```

Comment: Wild guess: If it isn't working, `DOMContentLoaded` may be too late. A MutationObserver that alters the elements at they get appended might work.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most tricky way:
Load a 1x1 px small-size loading image

```
<img src="/images/lazy.jpg" data-real-src="/images/OriginalImage-1.jpg">
<img src="/images/lazy.jpg" data-real-src="/images/OriginalImage--2.jpg">
<img src="/images/lazy.jpg" data-real-src="/images/OriginalImage--3.jpg">
```

Override lazy.jpg image to original image.

```
$('img[src="/images/lazy.jpg"]').each(function(index, el) {
    $(el).attr('src', $(el).data('real-src'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I cannot modify html. I can only run javascript